# How do I get the linebreaks in javascript/php when text auto-wraps

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a resizable `div` containing `text/sentences`. When I `resize` the `div`, the text automatically wraps to `fit` within the available space in the `container div`.

Now I need to convert this `text` to an image via `php` `(gd library)`, but since `php-gd` can't directly handle multiline texts, I need to somehow tell it where exactly the text wrapped and a new line begins, but I have no idea how to do this in either `javascript` or `php`.

Moreover the `font` is `dynamic` so I can't use something like the size of the `alphabets` to calculate the number of possible characters within a said `dimension`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a little trick... 
Wrap every character with a `<span></span>` and calculate their offset.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rmSYT/)

Code:

```
$('#Action').click(function(){
    var orginalText = $('#container').text();
    var characters = orginalText.split('');
    var wrappedText = "";
    for(var i =0; i< characters.length; i++){
        wrappedText += "<span id='wrapped_" + i + "'>" + characters[i] + "</span>";
    }

    $('#container').html(wrappedText);
    var top = 0;
    for(var i =0; i< characters.length; i++){
        var characterTop = $('#wrapped_'+i).offset().top;
        if(characterTop > top){
            console.log("line break at position " + i);
            top = characterTop;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome idea. Though I am gonna pass the offsets as an array map to php, this will let me do stuff like text alignments on the client-side and duplicate it on the backend. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to play with computed `height` and computed `line-height`. Both possible with for example `$('div').innerHeight()` or `$('div').css('lineHeight')`. You can find out how many lines is the text split into and then use some word-wrapping algorithm to add proper line endings yourself. The result may not be exactly as in the browser, but you can get close.